# Clustering multivariate time series - question regarding distance matrix

Tags: r, time, cluster-analysis, distance, series

I am trying to cluster meteorological stations using R. Stations provide such data as temperature, wind speed, humidity and some more on hourly intervals. I can easily cluster univariate time series using tsclust library, but when I cluster multivariate series I get errors.

I have data as a list so each list element is a matrix with time series data of one station (variables are columns and rows are different timestamp).

If I run:

```
tsclust(data, k = 2,
                   distance = 'Euclidean',   seed = 3247, trace = TRUE)
```

I get error: Error in do.call(.External, c(list(CFUN, x, y, pairwise, if (!is.function(method)) get(method) else method), : not a scalar return value

The same error I get if I try to calculate only distance matrix using

```
dist(data, method="euclidean")
```

Maybe Euclidean distance can not be calculated for such data? If yes, then what distances could be calculated?

Answer (score 0):

You supposedly can still use Euclidean.

You just have to **implement it yourself**, because the standard method only works for vectors, not for matrixes. But that should be trivial to implement yourself.

You'll likely run into scaling problems though if your variables have different units and magnitudes.

Answer (score 0):

If your series have the same length,
you could just transform them into a vector and then re-adjust dimensions.
However, like Anony-Mousse mentioned,
using Euclidean distance with variables that have different scales could be problematic,
so considering normalizing with `zscore`:

```
series <- zscore(data)
pc <- tsclust(lapply(series, as.vector), distance="Euclidean", seed=3247L, trace=TRUE)

pc@datalist <- series
# replace ncol with the actual number of columns from your data
pc@centroids <- lapply(pc@centroids, matrix, ncol=3L)
```

Comment: So, you're just making each matrix into a long vector and running this as a univariate clustering. Is the univariate Euclidean distance of a long vector made from each variable equivalent to the multivariate Euclidean distance?

Comment: @JHegg Unfortunately, I cannot assert that based on what I know. It might be, but I don't know if there's a valid theoretical foundation for that. It's just a possibility, at least technically speaking.